# Find most representative image

Tags: machine-learning, python, image-classification

I have 1,000 photoshoot-quality images of pianos on white background with very little noise (people in the background, etc). How would I go about finding the piano image that looks most like the others? Alternatively, how would I find five pianos that look most like the "average" piano. I'm particularly looking for python libraries that may be helpful (I'm currently looking at skimage).

Answer (score 3):

Find a low-dimensional emdedding of the images using a nonlinear dimensionality reduction method like autoencoding, then select the image closest to the centroid in the embedding space.

Comment: For high-level objects like pianos how deep a network and how many days of training will be needed? Maybe quicker to use the top layer of already trained network such as GoogleNet?

Comment: Do you have a link to an example / code for reducing dimensionality of images?

Comment: It depends on your hardware, of course, Valentas. And sure, there's no harm in starting with a pretrained network. @user2726995: http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/dA.html

Answer (score 2):

You could use the OpenCV library, specifically, the [**Haar-Cascade technique**](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html) . The OpenCV is a computer vision library that have a python interface. You could take a look in [**this tutorial**](http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html) to start.